# What Prevents load voltage from Flowing into Vsupply in this circuit?

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

[image]

Here, U1 is an optocoupler called TLP250. It is powered by Vsupply which is 12 V. V2 is the load voltage and it is at 24V. But it can be as much as 200V.

My question is, that since both Vsupply and V2 share the same ground, what prevents current from V2 from flowing into the Vsupply ground when Q1 is conducting?

Comment: There's no circular path from any of the left side back to V2 - any current flow from V2 positive must equal the current flow into V2 negative.

Comment: Can you come up with a return path for the current if your current flows from V2 to Vsupply through your ground ?

Comment: They *don't* share the same ground in your schematic - LOAD is in the way. (Not relevant to your concern, but hey.)

Answer (score 0):

In a steady state there will be no current from the high voltage supply through the gate side since there is only one DC connection between the two. The gate itself being capacitive.

**However:** There is an AC path though the gate capacitance that will introduce a voltage on the gate when the high voltage supply is initially attached or powered on. That coupling will briefly turn on the MOSFET and apply power to the load. How long that pulse is will depend on how active the opto-coupler is at that point.

[image]

If the load is fast enough to react to that pulse, the effect can be problematic.

Inclusion of a gate protection zener as shown below is also prudent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1orNV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As [Tony mentions in his answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/361189/139766), any AC noise on the high voltage supply line will also couple though the MOSFET to the gate side to some extent.

Answer (score -1):

> What Prevents load voltage from Flowing into Vsupply in this circuit?

- DC none
- AC switched current vs induction and switched voltage by Miller capacitance in drain to gate.

What prevents the AC coupling?

1) shielding, twisted pair load wires and a CM choke with a “solid” gnd.

- the only shared current is the FET capacitance when switching and apparent ground shift.

  - Otherwise the Switch load supply loop is not shared but induced currents exist from mutual coupling can get into Vsupply and common mode paths.

  **Hence answer given is correct for AC noise on source.**

  - given a source impedance, the load regulates the source voltage by impedance ratios (t,f) and thus infers a connection from load current to source voltage of the driver the switched capacitance charging of each transition and reactive load.

2) **your load   shares the same ground, not V2.**

Comment: this is in the case of a high side configuration like in an inverter

Comment: Then your shared ground is not shown or incorrect if floating as you not shown a boost Voltage to turn on FET

Comment: Show me where you think 24V load current gets into 12V DC supply?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 the gate has it's own supply that floats with the source. No boost is required here. Really badly drawn schematic to confuse the submarines though.

Comment: Then this statement is false "Vsupply and V2 share the same ground" It would be correct to say "the load shares the same ground."

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Can you please explain your comment?

Comment: Which end of V2 is connected to 0V? neither.